# Insert multimedia message to MySQL database using PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, database

I was working on a website for which I was designing the conversation system (Post, comment, like, etc.) like what all social networking sites have.

I am trying to provide option for inserting smileys along with the normal text content in a textarea.

**My Questions**

1. How do I add images like smileys in a textarea (**which accepts only text by default**) as and when user selects one from the list or puts in the symbol
2. Once I have the textarea with smileys and normal text, what is the best way to store it in the MySQL database
3. When displaying the message with smileys, what is the best way to parse the message from the database

**NOTE**

I am aware of developing a conversation system with just plain text and files. I am just not sure how to add,store,display smileys.

I am already aware of plugins like Tinymce: http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/basic.php

But I want to know how to make my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`textarea` can't be used to display images,use a contenteditable div instead.

As for the backend,store data in the database regularly (ex: Store :) directly)
and maintain a common table/array where you replace these text with the image/smiley each time you display the data.

Comment: I have been thinking along similar lines but my main problem is client side. As we know textarea cant display images, I am not sure how to make a contenteditable div as you said. Thanks for your reply

Comment: @T.v.Vignesh   `contenteditable` is just a attribute for a element in HTML5.Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable) for more details. This lets you edit content of a element.

Comment: nice.. i just tested it and it works.. Great.. Will use it.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't having some kind of inline notation help here? You could have something like `[::smiley-XXX::]` where that represents a particular smile. So long as it's something users are unlikely to type by accident it'll be fine.

Then you need a way of converting that from text into HTML, where you inline the appropriate image.

Comment: Yup. But how will the user be able to see the smiley inline with the text they type? The main problem I have is giving the smiley input in the textarea which cant accept images. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: You can't do this with a standard `<textarea>`, you'll need to have one that's smarter than that, some kind of "WYSIWYG"-type editor. If you look at a lot of bulletin boards, they just leave it as raw text until rendered in HTML, so it might not be as big a deal as you think. Making your own TinyMCE-work-alike would be a *huge* undertaking, so find one that works and you can modify to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply bro. For now I think I should stick to HTML5's contenteditable.

Comment: `contenteditable` is the basis for all of these fancy editors, but they usually do a ton of work to lock it down so people can't paste in arbitrary content. Hope you're on the right track though.